# External Drive not showing up, light blinking, iMac

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, usb, external-disk

External Drive disconnected during backup but now it won't show up again. The light keeps blinking. How do I fix this problem?

What I tried and didn't work:

1. New USB cable
2. Connect it to a different Mac

The drive shows up on Terminal with
`diskutil list`
as

```
 /dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *2.0 TB     disk2
   1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS ⁨Diskname⁩                    2.0 TB     disk2s2
```

It can't be unmounted with diskutil unmount disk
No FSCK is running in Activity Monitor

What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Next to the apple icon in the left upper corner ( In Finder) click Finder , drop down menu choose preferences and see if its checked in sidebar.

Comment: The drive ended up showing up on Desktop but Finder freezes every time when I tried to do anything. Also the drive won't eject properly.